# MVC 5: How Does Application_PostAuthenticateRequest() get called in Global.asax?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When setting up custom principals for the `[Authorize]` attribute to work in Microsoft's MVC version 4 and 5, we need to go into Global.asax.cs and set up a method called `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest()`. I've done that in my current project, and it works just fine.

However, it really bugs me how much this seems like "magic". `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest()` is not a virtual method. I'm not overloading or implementing any existing method signature in the class. So how does the MVC framework know to call it? C# is a strongly typed language, after all, and you don't get to call a method on a class unless you know it's there.

The only way I can see doing it is via Reflection. Maybe going through the final object's methods and assigning any methods that match a certain signature to delegates. But I really have no idea. And I don't understand why the designers would do that rather than just implementing a virtual method.

So, in summary, (A) how is `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` being called when it's not a defined method of the global.asax class, and (B) why didn't they just make it a virtual method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a comprehensive article on that by Rick Strahl. In short, the runtime uses reflection on your global application class.

http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Jun/18/How-do-ASPNET-Application-Events-Work

This type of event wiring is usually called "automatic" and is also present at page level. For example, the `Page_Load` is called just because of the default auto wireup.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.autoeventwireup(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, that's a good article. I can't say I understand why they did it this way over virtual methods, though.

Comment: @Pharylon: I can't think of any reasonable reason, too. Such "magic" auto wiring seems to be against any oo common sense.

Comment: @Pharylon Seems like the text book case for an Interface. I think it's just one of those things that "works" and is low priority to receive any attention for refactoring in the future. There might also be some backwards compatibility concerns, though I'm not sure what those would be. It's definitely a poor design. Magic and logic do not mix.

Comment: That msdn link is in Polish. Here's the English version: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.autoeventwireup(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: As for the OO common sense: virtual methods wouldn't work, because the available events depend on what modules are actually loaded. As they can be changed dynamically from web.config, there is no place for virtual methods here.

Comment: @GáborG.: are you sure? We talk here about events on the global application class, these events are not dependant on the list of modules in any way. Also, while the list of modules can be changed in the web.config, the list is static in a sense that its change require the app pool to be restarted. Even if the global app events would depend on modules, the list of modules is known when the app starts. This means it is easy to call virtual/interface methods from all loaded modules in consecutive events of the pipeline.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: Besides the Application_* events, there are FormsAuthentication_* for example, which are not directly defined in the HttpApplication's source. Adding virtual methods to every possible event would make HttpApplication a monster. Interfaces may not be the way to go either, because one interface would contain many methods, or you would have too many interfaces with specific methods (events.)

Comment: @GáborG.: I get your point and it is valid if you consider all possible `XXX_YYY` defined in the global app class, where XXX could be something else than `Application`. This opens up an interesting question on whether the class that allows this is not trying to do too much.